# Controls in a modal Form doesn't get focus when called from onActivate of another form. Why?

Tags: delphi

In certain cases my application try to open a certain Form (Form2) automatically after another one (Form1) is shown. I'm using `onFormActivate` to call `ShowModal`, but after the second form is shown, it's controls are losing their focus.

To reproduce:

1. Create a new VCL Applicattion;
2. Create a second Form and drop a `TEdit` in it;
3. On Main Form add an `onFormActivate` listener;

'

```
procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2.ShowModal;
end;
```

After run you will see Form2 being shown. But the edit doesn't get the focus.
It works if I comment the `MainFormOnTaskbar` in the project file.

```
// Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
```

But that is not what I'm supposed to change. I would like to understand: Why the `TEdit` is losing the focus?

Comment: OnActivate occurs while the focus is switching. You're interrupting focus transfer when you activate another window. Unsupported/undefined/unreliable behavior follows. Do not try to workaround, implement differently.

Comment: Thanks @SertacAkyuz. I thought that `onActivate` occurrs just after the focus had changed. That's why I used `onActivate` instead of `onShow`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OnActivate` is triggered while focus is in progress of being shifting around.  Interrupting that process is a really bad idea.

If you want the `OnActivate` event to trigger a `ShowModal()` call, you should delay it using `PostMessage()` (or a short `TTimer`) so the message loop can finish processing the focus shift that is already in progress, and then can perform the `ShowModal()` when it is safe to do so.  For example:

```
const
  WM_SHOWMODAL_FORM2 = WM_APP + 1;

procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PostMessage(Handle, WM_SHOWMODAL_FORM2, 0, 0);
end;

procedure TForm1.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if Message.Msg = WM_SHOWMODAL_FORM2 then
    Form2.ShowModal
  else
    inherited;
end;
```

Comment: The only difference to the way that I implemented is that I used a "message method" instead of overwriting WndProc.

Comment: I prefer to override `WndProc()` as it allows the Form unit to hide the details about which particular messages it processes. Using a `message` handler may be easier to code, but it also exposes information that does not need to be public to other units. Also, `WndProc()` is called first before any `message` handlers, so it is a little bit more efficient to override `WndProc()` and avoid the overhead of dispatch table lookups.  But either approach will work fine.